# Getting rid of the Antivirus 2009 virus/adware?

Tags: anti-virus, spyware, virus-removal, adware

I have known a few computers that have gotten this pesky virus/adware combination (my parents and girlfriend most notably). For my parents computer I resorted to reformatting it. I still don't know if it is off of my girlfriend's computer, as she took matters into her own hands. It doesn't seem like the average antivirus or antispyware programs do anything for it (Adaware, norton, avg). Is there any way to get rid of this pesky problem without resorting to a complete reformatting of the computer?

Here is the screenshot of the virus in action.

[image: antivirus 2009]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a guide and information: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/uninstall-antivirus-2009

Apparently it is a rogue advertising program disguised as anti-spyware software. Once installed it pops up these "warnings" telling you to purchase the software advertised.

Answer (score 2):

The guide that "lc" gave you is where I'd go. You can also post a HijackLog in the BleepingComputer forum if you want guided help. The problem with a lot of these rogues is that they download/install more "little friends". In a lot of cases with Vundo/rootkit infection, flattening the system is the best bet. Very few machines that come into my shop that are severely infected with rogues/rootkits/respawning garbage are salvageable from a practical (time=money for both me and the client) standpoint. You did the right thing. I hope it's OK to point you to my website (there are no ads and if it isn't OK I hope the moderators will tell me since I'm new here), but here's a link to my usual malware removal steps:

http://www.elephantboycomputers.com/page2.html#Removing_Malware

Comment: I agree. Reinstall or restore from a known good image.